# Does wordnet API has a function ".is_parent_of()"?

Tags: python, api, wordnet

I want to check if 'worda' is a hypernym of 'wordb', according to the wordnet words hierarchy relationship.

Does wordnet api NLKT has a function like

```
worda.is_parent_of(wordb)
```

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

There is the hypernyms() method for synsets. Also lowest_common_hypernyms() can be useful.Bear in mind that synsets can contain more than one word.Some example code to navigate wordnet can be found below.

```
from nltk.corpus import wordnet as wn
right_whale = wn.synset('right_whale.n.01')
orca = wn.synset('orca.n.01')
print orca
print right_whale.lowest_common_hypernyms(orca)
baleen_whale = right_whale.hypernyms()[0]
print baleen_whale
```